# Open dialogue with a bare bones version of Perl

Tags: perl, user-interface

I have a bare bones installation of Perl and I would like to create an dialogue box asking for a file and/or folder location to run the script on/in.

This is my work computer and I needed permission to install Perl - IT ignored my request (they didn't *deny* it). I happened to find a stripped down version of Perl installed with another program and have been using that to script with. It had exactly 3 modules and I added strict and warnings.

I understand that there are modules out there to do this (TK being the most popular), but they are dependent upon other modules (AutoLoader, DynaLoader, ...) which are probably dependent upon others. Sneaking two modules in was one thing...sneaking a dozen+ is another.

*Edit (from below)*: Another complication. My immediate team members use my scripts and they all have the bare-bones install of Perl, because they all have the parent program. The first time someone uses one of my Perl scripts I set the file association and add strict and warnings (so I don't have to remember to comment them out). Thus - I would like to keep as simple of a setup as possible.

---

All my scripts currently run on the folder they are located in. This is getting unwieldy due to changes in the scripts over time. My current plan is to utilize a prompt on the command line - having the user copy the file path from windows explorer and then analyzing it with regex. I foresee a couple issues with this:

- Pasting into a command prompt is annoying
- Need to be careful about crossing network drives (C > G > N)
- spaces/weird characters/slashes going the right way
- Making sure the script operates in the "new" input location

This seems doable, yet I wanted to see if there would be a friendlier way to do this (esp to get around the command prompt paste annoyance).

Hopefully the question isn't too broad for this forum - if not I'll come back later with some attempted code.

---

**OS:** Windows 7 Professional (64 bit)

**Perl:** ActiveState Version 5.6.0 (downloaded Feb 21, 2001)

**Modules currently available:** Exporter, RE, utf8, strict & warnings. Generally this works well enough since I'm typically just doing file manipulations.

Comment: See if you can install the PortableZIP version of Strawberry Perl.

Comment: Are you sure you can't install it at all? Have you tried? (5.6 is pretty old.) Are you writing this script for other people to use?

Comment: My immediate team members use my scripts and they all have the bare-bones install of Perl, because they all have the parent program. The first time someone uses one of my Perl scripts I set the file association and add strict and warnings (so I don't have to remember to comment them out). Thus - I would like to keep as simple of a setup as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not going to get much out of a 13 year old version of Perl that may not even include all of the 5.6 modules. Is this perchance a Rational package that installed this version of Perl? If it's ClearCase, there's a program called `clearprompt`. You can try that.

I know this isn't what you want to here, but forget about Perl, and try it in [PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx).

PowerShell is an under utilized programming language created by Microsoft specifically for Windows. It is a full fledge programming language that integrates tightly with Windows. It is highly object oriented. It can display [dialog boxes](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/09/01/hey-scripting-guy-september-1.aspx) And, most importantly, it comes on all Windows Machines since Windows XP. This means that if you write a PowerShell application, all of your colleagues can use it.

My entire Powershell experience consists of three programs. I usually work in Unix/Linux environments and mainly on the server side. However, we had a client that needed a special script to monitor some processes and to email support if these processes weren't updated in certain time frames.

It would be a cinch to do in Perl, but they didn't have Perl or Python and I was told that nothing could be installed on these systems. I had to use whatever tools were already there, so my only choice was PowerShell.

In the end, Powershell worked pretty well and it wasn't that difficult to pick up. My main problem is that all I could find was PowerShell 2 documentation, but the servers where the script had to run were using PowerShell 1. Even worse, my system has PowerShell 2, so I would run a script on my system, then found it didn't work on the customer's system. However, I did get the hang of PowerShell and still delivered the program to the customer on time.

If you know VB, the PowerShell syntax should be fairly familiar, but even if you're not familiar with VB, you shouldn't have any problems picking up the syntax if you've done any object oriented programing.  So, as much as I like programming in Perl, you are in an environment that is very limited. Might as well use the tools that the environment provides you.

Comment: Stop using perl?!? TRAITOR! Just kidding ;-)   I have many completed scripts in Perl that work - so writing, debugging, fixing, and debugging each in a new language doesn't sound doable at this time. HOWEVER, I already use perl to call other processes and languages (saxon/imageMagick/system commands/etc). Do you think it would be possible to write a "getMyFile" program in PowerShell, call it from Perl and get the result?  Actually, it should be possible....will it be a mini-purgatory to get it to work?

Comment: Yew, that is possible. Remember you have to call your program as a parameter of the powershell command.

Comment: Although I ended up just using the command prompt I think this "answers" the question (best practice) and I will be continuing to look into Powershell. Side question - you wouldn't happen to know a good place to get an overview of the "grammar". I found a half hour video in which the presenters spend 20 minutes telling us how awesome they were before finally showing how to open a powershell window and change the display prefs.

Comment: And I take that question back - I just found this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956109/looking-for-quick-and-complete-powershell-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Look into [`PAR::Packer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp).  It will enable you to create standalone executables from Perl programs.

Perhaps the fact that all of the modules you'd use are isolated to this single executable and not available system wide will make it easier for IT to give a blanket approval for your specific script.

Comment: I remember looking into standalone executables in the past but was stopped for some reason. That was at least 5 years ago though, so things may be different now. It's a useful idea, but I can't upvote yet (hopefully one day - there is a great answer on running schematron from the command line that I need to give kudos to).

Answer (score 0):

A stripped down perl 5.6 is not going to have what you want to accomplish your goal. Your only option for perl 5.6 would be to pick a GUI library you already have installed (or native WinForms), and manually program a pure perl interface to their API.

You can use a portable version of a programming language where you have some more control, but I would never recommend working against your I.T. team. You should be working together.

If you're on Windows 7, look into PowerShell. It should have a lot more native functionality to accomplish your goal.

Comment: By "portable version" are you speaking of the same thing as Miller with PAR::Packer creating a standalone executable?

A big "yes" on working with IT. They know I utilize the Perl already installed - I'm not sure they are enthusiastic about it, but they know my coworkers and I script in various languages.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't -- Strawberry Perl has a version that you can unzip (http://strawberryperl.com/download/5.18.2.2/strawberry-perl-5.18.2.2-32bit-portable.zip) and just run the perl.exe. There's nothing inherent to Perl that requires it be "installed" in anyway. You could even download the modules you wanted, put them in a local folder somewhere, and use perl's -I command to tell perl to look there for modules. If IT's ok with that, both are good options.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Zenity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity) or [Wenity](http://search.cpan.org/src/TOBYINK/Alien-Wenity-0.000_01/share/Wenity.exe). Zenity is a small command-line program that displays a GUI dialog box for the user to interact with, and once they've hit "OK", prints their response to STDOUT. Though Zenity itself can usually be persuaded run on Windows, it's non-native, so doesn't have the normal Windows "look and feel". Wenity is my loose port of Zenity to Windows and .NET, as a small, standalone, zero-install .exe file.

You can display a file open dialog box roughly like this:

```
my $filename = `/path/to/zenity --file-selection --title="Select input file"`;
chomp($filename);
```

Wenity should work roughly the same.